# Is it possible to use ProgressBarPager with a buffered Store(buffered:true) in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am trying to create a ProgressBarPager grid in ExtJs using a remote store with buffering(buffered:true). This is not a scrollable grid. I am not looking for an infinite scroll grid with bufferedrenderer plugin. I need to display the pagination tool bar and limit the number of lines on the page.

When user clicks on next or previous button, I would expect the store to use the pre-fetched data to render the screen first and then go and load more data from the server. But, currently it looks like the pre-fetching is happening first and then the rendering. So, buffering is not helping in rendering the page fast when user clicks on next or previous.

I know buffering will work fine in scrollable grids. Is it even possible to use buffering in combination with a non scrolling grid?

Please let me know if you have any pointers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, you can't do it. You need to do either buffering or paging, not both.

Comment: Thanks Evan for the reply!. I am trying to make the page navigation smoother. Can you suggest any alternatives? (unfortunately I have to use pagination toolbar and can’t use BigData style grids)